# Parent branch in TFS missing old changesets that are in child branch. Need to re-sync them

Tags: tfs, merge, tfvc

We have a main work branch that is a child of the Production branch.  All work is done in the work branch (or below) and merged in to Production only when we release code.  We recently found that there are changesets missing from our Production branch that should have been merged in months ago.  But we've merged the work branch in to Production several times since then.  I don't know how many changesets are missing, but we are about to have a release and I would like to use this chance to fix this.

Is there a way to overwrite a parent branch (similar to when you overwrite your local copy with latest from source)?

I know I can force changesets, but that requires knowing what changesets to force. Is there a way to identify differences in the changesets included in two branches?

My last resort is to nuke the parent branch and just create a new one, but that seems heavy handed and really isn't ideal.

Comment: What's that mean for `missing old changesets` here? do you mean that the changes made in the old changesets are missed? or just cannot see the old changsets number which merged from child branch?

Comment: It means that I identified some code that was missing (library failed to build) and I tracked it back through history to find the changeset it was in.  I spot checked a few of the other files in that changeset and they were all missing in my production branch.  The changeset is a descendant (great great grandchild?) of the production branch and branches between it and production have the changeset, as well as all of their siblings.  But it's not in Production.  I know I can force that one, but I don't know what else may be missing.

Comment: `Is there a way to identify differences in the changesets included in two branches?` You can compare the changsets between two branches with specifying the target path manually such as `$/Scrum-TFVC/TestTargetBranch`, by default it's local workspace. Then select the specific changesets to compare. If you find the specific changeset, then you can merge again...